# Why is there a mysterious empty space below my flexbox container on mobile and how can I fix it?

Tags: css, mobile, flexbox, touch

I have a flexbox container with two items in it. I don't want them to shrink to fit the viewport width, so I've set flex-shrink to 0. For some reason, a big empty space appears below my container. Inspecting the page, nothing seems to be there, it's just empty.

The problem appears on mobile (Firefox and Chrome) and when I have touch simulation enabled with the dev-tools on Firefox desktop. Disabling touch simulation removes the empty space.

I've been pretty successful at isolating the issue, so this is all the css and html I need to reproduce it:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

The empty space disappears if I only have one .item, or if I set the container's overflow-x to auto - but in the latter case, I get a horizontal scrollbar on the container itself, which is not what I want.

Comment: Don't see the problem using your code. https://jsfiddle.net/jd85mLtu/

Comment: Oh, it's there. If you're using Firefox, you can right-click the preview frame and go "this frame"->"show only this frame". Then hit ctrl-shift-m to go to responsive design mode, and there it is!

Comment: ...I've uploaded the code here to make it simpler: http://fortelle.no/prosjekter/test.html

just open it on mobile to see it, or use the responsive design mode of Firefox, or your browser's equivalent.

Comment: IT's because body has a default css with margin:8px

Comment: This is far more than 8px, and it becomes bigger the more items I add, so that can't be it.

Incidentally, the empty space disappears if I set the container's overflow-x to auto, or if I only have one .item

Comment: share a screenshot

Comment: It seems like `flex-shrink: 0` is forcing adherence to the aspect ratio. Try Grid instead? https://jsfiddle.net/3ns4rm1v/

Comment: Here's a screenshot, Temani. As you can see, it's a fair bit more than 8px :)

https://imgur.com/a/wNRmhPv

Comment: Thanks for the code, Michael, but... it looks like it has the same problem! ...at least on the responsive design mode with Firefox desktop.

I've hacked together a solution by just setting the container's overflow to auto on devices with touch screens (given that scroll bars tend to be more subtle there, it looks and works acceptable). I'm still really curious about what the issue is here, though. What aspect ratio is it forcing, where does it come from?